# Concat values to string array postgres

Tags: postgresql

I want to reach following structure:

```
["687ccca","da075bd","4194d"]
```

and try to achieve it like this:

```js
UPDATE table1
SET "ids"= CONCAT  ('[', result, ']')
FROM (SELECT string_agg(  id::character varying, ', ')
FROM   table2 where "name" like '%W11%'
or "name" like '%12%'
or "name" like '%13%'
or "name" like '%5%'
or "name" like '%W9%'
or "name" like '%74%'
) AS result
WHERE "ids"='all';
```

however I get this:

```
[("df6bd58d, 26e094b, 637c1, 4a8cf387ff43c5, 9b0bf9f")]
```

How do I remove `(` and `)` and add `"` after each id?

Comment: Maybe like this? `CONCAT('["', string_agg(id::character varying, '", "'), '"]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to get an JSON array:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9eea06d39b1216f5d2287b6df63f0b84)

```
SELECT
    json_agg(your_texts)
FROM
    your_table
```

If you really want text you can cast this result with ::text into a text afterwards:

```
json_agg(your_texts)::text
```

Comment: You're hero! Thank you!